# Updating by reference a data.table using another, but only empty values

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to update some *dt1* data.table using another *dt2* data.table on common id for a specific column. That specific column should be updated only if the value of the specific column in *dt1* is empty (NA).

For instance, this updates everything :

```
dt1 <- data.table(
  "id" = c(1,2,3,4),
  "animal" = c("cat","cat","dog",NA)
)
dt2 <- data.table(
  "id" = c(3,4),
  "animal" = c("human being","duck")
)


dt1 <- dt1[dt2, on = c("id"),"animal" := .(i.animal)]
```

Which gives for *dt1*

```
id   animal
1:  1      cat
2:  2      cat
3:  3      human being
4:  4      duck
```

While I need

```
id   animal
1:  1      cat
2:  2      cat
3:  3      dog
4:  4     duck
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `fcoalecse`

```
library(data.table)
dt1[dt2, animal := fcoalesce(animal, i.animal), on = .(id)]
```

-output

```
> dt1
      id animal
   <num> <char>
1:     1    cat
2:     2    cat
3:     3    dog
4:     4   duck
```